# Why do some Azure App Insight metrics not appear in the Portal?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights, metrics

I've implemented custom metrics into my app, so that these are sent to App Insights in Azure:

```
using (var operation = tc.StartOperation<DependencyTelemetry>("MetricName"))
{
  //some long running code
}
```

If I run this code say, **5 times**, and then go look at the App Insights metrics in the Azure Portal:

```
dependencies 
| where type == 'Other'
```

Then I'll usually see about **1-2 entries** for this metric with timestamps. I've repeated this over and over and it's always the same, what happens to the other missing metrics given that the code ran **5** times? (with considerable delay between each run)

I wondered if they were being filtered out from sampling, but according to the docs App Insights does not sample metrics: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling

*"Application Insights does not sample session, metrics (including custom metrics), or performance counter telemetry types in any of the sampling techniques. These types are always excluded from sampling as a reduction in precision can be highly undesirable for these telemetry types."*

I can confirm it's not a delay, I've tried waiting many hours to see if the missing ones appear. Any ideas?

Comment: For sampling you can check itemCount on your dependency telemetry items. If it is not 1 then some items were sampled out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uhm, you are tracking a dependency, not a metric (those are stored in the customMetrics table). And since you are tracking dependencies sampling might be the cause.

To track metrics use the method described [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/get-metric#sending-metrics):

```
_telemetryClient.GetMetric("myMetric").TrackValue(42);
```

> If we want to simply time the duration of a block of code inside a using statement, is StartOperation() not the way to go then? Is that some other concept than metrics?

It is definitely an option as the dependency telemetry does store the time spend executing. But it is stored in a different table than a metric and is subject to sampling. So you can exclude the dependency from sampling but that might cause a lot of data ingestion. Or you create your own code to track a metric like this:

```cs
public class MetricOperation : IDisposable
{
    private readonly TelemetryClient _tc;
    private readonly Stopwatch _sw = new Stopwatch();
    private readonly string _operationName;
    
    public MetricOperation(TelemetryClient tc, string operationName)
    {
        _tc = tc;
        _operationName = operationName;
        
        _sw.Start();
    }
    
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _sw.Stop();
        _tc.GetMetric(_operationName).TrackValue(_sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

and call it like this

```cs
using(new MetricOperation(tc, "metricName"))
{
    // some long running operation
}
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you, the docs confused many of us. If we want to simply time the duration of a block of code inside a using statement, is StartOperation() not the way to go then? Is that some other concept than metrics?

Comment: Thanks for this, I was also wondering whether subclassing OperationTelemetry was an alternative option - if there's a way to specify that it should go into the CustomMetrics table that is

Comment: @FBryant87 I don't think that is possible. But do let me know if it is ;-)